# About group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dynamical-systems

Let D={$n_{i}$} be a sequence of integers, $n_{i+1}$ is a multiple of $n_{i}$ ($\forall i$) and $n_{i} \to \infty$. Let us consider a group $H(D)\subset \mathbb{Z}_{n_{0}} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_{1}}\times \dots$, defined in the following way $$H(D)=\{(r_{0},r_{1},\dots) : r_{i+1}\equiv r_{i} (mod \ m_{i})\}$$

I have two questions, the group operation is to sum term by term? And what is the minimal shift in $H(D)$ by the element $(1,1,\dots)$?

Article: [link](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~ablokh/gustrow.pdf)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Presumably one would use the group operation of the group it is a subset of. However this seems to me to be a definition in some paper/text taken out of context and someone reading this question can't really know the right answer without more details.

Comment: @MattSamuel [link](http://people.cas.uab.edu/~ablokh/gustrow.pdf) pg.3

Comment: I think by the minimal shift $\tau$ by the element $(1,1,\ldots)$, they mean the map $\tau \colon H(D) \to H(D)$ which sends $(r_0, r_1, \ldots)$ to $(r_0+1, r_1+1, \ldots)$.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I can only guess that maybe they mean that it's minimal in the sense that it only adds a generator in each component (and not elements of lower order). I have seen similar maps in ergodic theory (based on the bibliography, ergodic theory/dynamical systems could be relevant). E.g., on $\mathbb Z_n$ the map $x \mapsto x + 1$ is ergodic w.r.t. the discrete topology. Similarly, on the circle, $S^1$, rotation by an irrational angle $\beta$, $\exp(i2\pi \alpha) \mapsto \exp(i2\pi(\alpha+\beta))$ is ergodic w.r.t. the usual topology. My guess is that something similar is discussed here.

Answer (score 1):

The group operation in the direct product $\mathbb Z_{n_0} \times \mathbb Z_{n_1} \times \cdots$ is indeed to sum term by term.  As $H(D)$ is a subgroup of this product it uses the same group operation so you are correct, the group operation on $H(D)$ is to sum term by term.

<strike>By "minimal shift" I assume you're asking what the order of the element $(1, 1, \ldots)$ is, let me know if you meant something else.  Anyway, $(1, 1, \ldots)$ has infinite order because for any $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $n\cdot(1, 1, \ldots) = (n, n, \ldots)$ and $(n, n, \ldots) \neq (0, 0, \ldots)$ because the limit of the $n_i$ is infinity so there is some $i$ such that $n_i > n$ and hence $n \neq 0 \pmod{n_i}$.</strike>

Comment: I imagine that such shift is a action between H(D) and a given set.

Comment: For your second paragraph, the OP doesn't know what minimal shift means. Look at the linked paper. I don't think it means what you wrote, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yea, I wrote the second paragraph before they posted that link, I agree that order is probably not what they're talking about.